# Accessing an asp.net web service with classic asp

Tags: asp.net, post, asp-classic, get

My company is considering working with another company on a particular module.  Information would be sent back and forth between us through my web service.  Thing is, my web service uses ASP.NET, and they use classic ASP.  Everything I've found online says (it's a pain, but) they can communicate, but I'm not clear on some details.

Specifically, do I have to enable GET and POST on my web service?  If I don't *have* to, but could, would enabling them make the communication significantly easier/better?  And finally, GET and POST are disabled by default because of security.  What are the security risks involved in enabling them?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP.NET web services, but if *both* GET and POST are disabled, how is another application supposed to communicate with the service?

Comment: SOAP is enabled http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267

Comment: It would depend on what sort of information you're passing back and forth -- for example, simple XML would work well with either (or any) platform. If you edit the question with some specifics about the data you're exchanging, we could post a better answer.

Comment: I haven't written the functions yet, so it's still pretty flexible.  I can convert most of it to xml easily enough, but what about my soap headers? Those affected too?

Answer (score 0):

My first question should be "Why use Soap?".  The simplest common demoninator that you have between the two is XML so thats a given.  However the choice of transport can be as simple as an single .ashx or as clever as WCF service.

Since your first consumer is using ASP why use a technology that makes it difficult for them?

The true bottom line here is what are your security requirements?

Comment: They're not my first consumer of my web service, they're just the first consumers of about 3 functions in my web service.  That said, if there's a simple way to allow them access to those 3 functions by taking them out and putting them in their own service/handler/whatever, I'm all ears. 
Mostly, I need to be able to verify username and password before they can use the functions, and I need the solution to be simple enought that I can get them a working version by next week.

Comment: Are all requests expected to be verified with a username and password or just an initial one?  Is plain text passing of the password sufficient?   Is there a VPN or SSL involved that might make such plain text usage sufficient?  Do the ASPers on the other end have access to VB6 and the SOAP Toolkit?  The list detail needed to make a success of this may continue.